# How do I measure the time my function, and only my function is using the CPU

Tags: c++, benchmarking

I am using GCC on ubuntu, and I want a function that does measures the time that my function uses the CPU. I do not want to include the time that the CPU spent on background processes.

For example, if my function used the CPU for 10 ms, then the processor processed some other data for 20 ms, then continued working on my function for 8 ms. I want it to return 18ms, not 38. I don't mind if the result was in CPU ticks.

Comment: Does "my function" mean the entire program(In that case, just use the time program), or do you really only want to time the cpu usage of a specific subset of your program?

Comment: This is known as "CPU time" instead of "wall clock time"

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is called profiling and `gprof` on Linux is quite handy for that, see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-gnuprof.html.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of Baris Demiray I can personally recommend the callgrind tool (as well as any other tool) of the valgrind toolset. This is especially useful in combination with kcachegrind/qcachegrind which should be available through the ubuntu repositories.

A very brief description of both tools, gprof and callgrind can be found here:
http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Introduction.html

Answer (score -2):

You want to take a look at `clock()` (`man 3 clock`).

Comment: Not one of them, but maybe it's because `clock()` isn't well suited for this in a multithreaded, multicore scenario, since the cputime will be accumulated from all executors, making it progress faster than waltime.